# kml update through networklinkcontrol not updating

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am trying to update a kml file through the networkcontrollink with an update
The kml file i want to update is stored on the server is called initial_coord.kml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
<Document>
  <Placemark id="pm123">
    <name>point123</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-95.44,40.42,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark id="pm456">
    <name>point456</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-95.43,40.42,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The kml file i load to update it is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLink>
  <name>Update</name>
  <Link>
    <href>http://localhost/cgi-bin/testF/add_more_coords.py</href></Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

And the python script i am calling is the following

```
#!/usr/bin/python
kml= (
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
    '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">\n'
    '<NetworkLinkControl>\n'
    '<Update>\n'
    '<targetHref>http://10.10.210.247/initial_coords.kml</targetHref>\n'
    '<Change>\n'
    '<Placemark targetId="pm123">\n'
    '<name>Name changed by Update Change</name>\n'
    '<!-- coordinates remain the same -->\n'
    '</Placemark>\n'
    '</Change>\n'
    '</Update>\n'
    '</NetworkLinkControl>\n'
    '</kml>\n'
    )
print 'Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml\n'
print kml
```

The update does not work and i am wondering why because it is very similar to the google example

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkLinkControl is strict regarding the target URL and you have *localhost* in the root KML and 10.10.210.247 in the python-generated output. Most match exactly to work correctly.

```
<Link>
    <href>http://localhost/cgi-bin/testF/add_more_coords.py</href></Link>
</NetworkLink>

<Update>
    '<targetHref>http://10.10.210.247/initial_coords.kml</targetHref>\n'
<Update>
```

You'll notice the targetUrl and NetworkLink URL matching in the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates).

Try putting the IP address in the root KML file to match what is generated in the python.

```
<NetworkLink>
  <Link>
    <href>http://10.10.210.247/cgi-bin/testF/add_more_coords.py</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>

<Update>
    '<targetHref>http://10.10.210.247/cgi-bin/testF/add_more_coords.py</targetHref>\n'
<Update>
```

Comment: Wait what do you mean? It doesnt complain about the network link cause its green but it just doesnt update.
I also tried doing googles exact example by having the update_coords.kml become:
exactly what google had on its example but just used my url for the kml file. I didnt use a script and it still didnt work. I did what google did but still didnt work

Comment: So since i am trying to use a python script how do i use the same ip?
I put my python script in the CGI_Executables in /Library/WebServer/ I tried to use the url http://10.10.10.24/cgi-bin/pythonScript.py If my IP is 10.10.10.24?
It works for kml files if i put it in the directory Documents and use the url http://10.10.10.24/kmlFile.kml but i need to switch to a python file and im not sure how to do that. I tried finding thigns online but i cant seem to find it.

Comment: The initial KML and python script should have the URLs matching -- try putting KML on same machine as that running python CGI script. Also note the URL for the NetworkLink must be same as target in networkLinkControl.